# What is the python equivalent of curl -x

Tags: python-3.x, rest, curl, python-requests

What is the -x option in curl and how to implement equivalent command in python using the requests library.
I want the following command to be in python.

```
curl \
  -X DELETE \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import requests

headers = {'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json'}

response = requests.delete(url='https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world', headers=headers)
```

`-X DELETE` is the HTTP method you are using, here we use `delete` method from `requests` module

`-H` is to specify the request headers, here we achieve it with `headers` parameter

Answer (score 0):

I believe this would be:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
}

response = requests.delete('https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world', headers=headers)
```

Another alternative would be to use `PycURL`, which provides the `setopt` option:

```
crl = pycurl.Curl()
crl.setopt(crl.URL, "<url here>")
crl.setopt(crl.CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE")
```